# I need to create dynamic tables using htmltextwriter or some equivalent to html textwriter?

Tags: .net-core

I am migrating a project from MVC to .NET Core. While migrating I have came across `Htmltextwriter` in MVC. How I will convert those into .NET Core?

Comment: you can move the logic to .Net Standard 2.0 and their you can use HtmlTextWriter and reference it in .NetCore

Comment: is this the only solution ? we cant build the same using .net core solution?

Comment: if you wish to reinvent the wheel then you definitely can give a try there must be an alternative but i also have faced a similar issue so opted using .Net Standard as it saved my time and worked like a charm

Comment: do you have any idea..how to do the workaround?

Comment: In,netstandart also html textwriter is not supported

Comment: try https://forums.websharper.com/blog/84664

Answer (score 1):

The conversion is easy: just install NuGet package HtmlTextWriter in your .NET core project. To use it, reference it by adding "using System.Web.UI". After doing this, you don't need to change any of your code that uses Htmltextwriter.

I've tested this and it's working on .NET core 3.1 and .NET 5. It doesn't work for .NET core 2 or lower.